# Media-query width not being followed

Tags: css, media-queries

I currently have a footer with 3 sections layed out as follows:

```
.foot1, .foot2, .foot3 { width: 33%; float: left; }
.foot2 { margin: 0 0.5%; }
```

I want them to change layout at 768px and 480px.  At 768px, I have the following (to stack the first on top, with the #2 & 3 splitting the space underneath it):

```
.foot1 { width: 98%; float: none; margin: 0 1%; }
.foot2, .foot3 { width: 48%; margin: 0 1%; }
```

At 480px (to have all 3 stack and take up the width) I have:

```
.foot2, .foot3 { width: 98%; float: none; }
```

My problem is that at 480px and under, the widths are not being followed and are still staying at 48%.  If I use 'inspect' in Chrome, I can see that the 'float: none;' is being followed, but not the width from the media-query.

Does anyone have any idea why it would choose to recognize the float declaration but not the width: 98%?

Thanks!

Comment: Certainly it shouldn't do that but the first explanation that comes to mind is that you're not using the same level of specificity for each media query (unless of course, you actually have foot1, foot2 and foot3 instead of something like "div#container div.element div.foot1"). By the way, you know if you're using the correct media query when you see something similar to "@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)" below "Matched CSS Rules".

Comment: Can you paste the media-query css please? I'm referring to the `@media screen` parts.

Comment: If you have `float: none`, your display is not automatically set to `block`. What is the CSS display setting? If it is inline, there is no use of width declaration.

Comment: Did you inspect it with Firebug? You can see, where the actual CSS in charge  comes from

Comment: The author of this question hasn't been seen since last year. Presumably, it's @catandmouse that needs to answer these questions, if he is indeed having the exact same problem. I'm not sure why a bounty was placed on this..

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to reproduce the issue you are having but was unable to do so.

I believe that my test code below works as you desire. How is your code different from the below html/css?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .foot1 { background: tan }
    .foot2 { background: green }
    .foot3 { background: blue }
    .foot1, .foot2, .foot3 { width: 33%; float: left; }
    .foot2 { margin: 0 0.5%; }
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .foot1 { width: 98%; float: none; margin: 0 1%; }
      .foot2, .foot3 { width: 48%; margin: 0 1%; }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      .foot2, .foot3 { width: 98%; float: none; }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="foot1">foot1</div><div class="foot2">foot2</div><div class="foot3">foot3</div>
</body>
</html>
```